# SQL Row wise total value

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have a table named `calcu`

```
id    date         name   s1      s2    s3    s4    min_value   
1   02/10/2017    dicky   7       4     8     9       4         
2   02/10/2017    acton   12      15    17    19      15        
3   02/10/2017    adney   28      13    19    10      13
```

[This is my table in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31579c/3)

I need `row wise total value`. I means in a new column `total`, it will be (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4) i.e. (7+4+8+9) = `28 where id=1`, (12+15+17+19)=`63 where id=2`, (28+13+19+10)=`70 where id=3` respectively.

Result will be like below:

```
id    date         name   s1      s2    s3    s4    min_value   Total
1   02/10/2017    dicky   7       4     8     9       4         28
2   02/10/2017    acton   12      15    17    19      15        63
3   02/10/2017    adney   28      13    19    10      13        70
```

[see my problem here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31579c/5)

It results all total 161 and 3 rows become 1 row.

How to write SQL query?

Comment: Hint:  `s1 + s2 + s3 + d4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUM()` function is an aggregate function. As with other aggregates, use it only to compute values across multiple rows.

You want to add up values in one row, so just use the `+` operator (brackets are optional).

As for finding the minimum value in the row, use `CASE WHEN` with 3 tests, comparing S1, S2, S3 and S4.

This should work:

```
select 
  c.id, c.date, c.name, c.s1, c.s2, c.s3, c.s4, 
  (c.s1 + c.s2 + c.s3 + c.s4) as total,
  case 
    when c.s1 <= c.s2 and c.s1 <= c.s3 and c.s1 <= c.s4 then c.s1
    when c.s2 <= c.s1 and c.s2 <= c.s3 and c.s2 <= c.s4 then c.s2
    when c.s3 <= c.s2 and c.s3 <= c.s1 and c.s3 <= c.s4 then c.s3
    when c.s4 <= c.s2 and c.s4 <= c.s3 and c.s4 <= c.s1 then c.s4
  end as min_value
from calcu c
;
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31579c/12/0)

Comment: If you carefully check your answer in SQL Fiddle, `min_value column has been changed` which is the lowest value column i.e. after totaling all the fields column wise, as s1 sum = 47, s2 sum = 32, s3 sum = 44, s4 sum = 38

Answer (score 1):

```
select  c.id, 
       c.date, c.name, c.s1, c.s2, c.s3, c.s4, 
       least(s1,s2,s3,s4) Minvalue, 
       (s1+s2+s3+s4) Total
from calcu c
```

I tried simplifying the query. So you are looking for the minimum value among s1,s2,s3 and s4. You can achieve with least function. And you need a total of all four 's' columns. Just add them

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *,s1+s2+s3+s4 as Total FROM `calcu`

Comment: Code only answers aren't useful for the community. Please look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)